# How convert struct to string (valid url format) and then parse the same struct again from it?

Tags: swift, struct, decode, encode

I want to convert my structs to the "string" so I can add them to the URL and reread them later from another URL.

here is how I wanted to do it, but it's not working and I have no idea why.

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    var number: Int
    var title: String
    var arrayString: [String]
}
let myObject = MyObject(number: 2, title: "hello", arrayString: ["item 1", "item 2"])
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(myObject)
let stringData = data.base64EncodedString()
print("stringData:", stringData)
let validURL = URL(string: "https:google.com/" + stringData)
print("validURL:", validURL?.absoluteString ?? "")

if let newStringData = validURL?.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "https:google.com/", with: "").data(using: .utf8) {
    let newData = Data(base64Encoded: newStringData)
    if let newObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: newStringData) {
        print("new parsed object:", newObject)
    } else {
        print("shit!")
    }
} else {
    print("Oops")
}
```

Output:

stringData: https:google.com/eyJumluZyI6WyJpdGVtIDEiLCJpdGVtIDIiXX0=

validURL: https:google.com/https:google.com/eyJumluZyI6WyJpdGVtIDEiLCJpdGVtIDIiXX0=

shit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo. You have to decode `newData` rather than `newStringData`

You can figure it out yourself by`catch`ing the DecodingError.

And it's easier to get the `path` of the URL and drop the first – the slash – character

```
let myObject = MyObject(number: 2, title: "hello", arrayString: ["item 1", "item 2"])
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(myObject)
let stringData = data.base64EncodedString()
print("stringData:", stringData)
let validURL = URL(string: "https://google.com/" + stringData)
print("validURL:", validURL?.absoluteString ?? "")

if let newStringData = validURL?.path.dropFirst().data(using: .utf8) {
    let newData = Data(base64Encoded: newStringData)!
    do {
        let newObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: newData)
        print("new parsed object:", newObject)
    } catch {
        print("shit!", error)
    }
} else {
    print("Oops")
}
```